# How to automatically insert a copied row after a specific value in a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy

I have a table that contains a set of bundles that have to be broken down into their components. For this I'm looking for VBA instructions that will copy any row that contains the tag "-edubnd" at the end of the 'sku' cell (please see table bellow for example) twice underneath itself.

It might be easier to ignore the tag component and use a specific set of values that the code looks for, that's also possible as the values marked as bundles are always the same in the column. What I mean is, instead of looking for the -edubnd tag, the code just looks for a specific value in that column,

I have created a sample table below that is similar-enough to my table in excel that it should serve to illustrate the question.

I'm currently filtering out the dataset, copying it into a different excel document, then running this:

```
Sub insertrows()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xCount As Integer

LableNumber:
    xCount = 2
    For I = Range("A" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        Rows(I).Copy
        Rows(I).Resize(xCount).Insert
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

### Current table:

```
column1   |    column2    |  column3 |  column3
----------------------------------------------
  A       |      pear     |  blue    |  10
  A       |      apple    |  orange  |  50
  A       |      orange   |  yellow  |  30
  A       |      kiwi     |  yellow  |  20
  A       | orange-edubnd |  blue    |  100
  A       |      apple    |  green   |  10
  A       |  pear-edubnd  |  green   |  50
  A       |      mango    |  pink    |  60
```

### Desired table

**Note:** the copied row after each distinct column2 with the -edubnd tag

```
 column1   |    column2    |  column3 |  column3
----------------------------------------------
  A       |      pear     |  blue    |  10
  A       |      apple    |  orange  |  50
  A       |      orange   |  yellow  |  30
  A       |      kiwi     |  yellow  |  20
  A       | orange-edubnd |  blue    |  100
  A       | orange-edubnd |  blue    |  100
  A       | orange-edubnd |  blue    |  100
  A       |      apple    |  green   |  10
  A       |  pear-edubnd  |  green   |  50
  A       |  pear-edubnd  |  green   |  50
  A       |  pear-edubnd  |  green   |  50
  A       |      mango    |  pink    |  60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleased try this code after making the appropriate modifications to its parameters.

```
Sub InsertDuplicates()

    Const TestClm As String = "B"               ' modify as appropriate
    Const SearchCrit As String = "edubnd"

    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InsRows")     ' change as appropriate
        For R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TestClm).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If InStr(1, .Cells(R, TestClm).Value, SearchCrit, vbTextCompare) Then
                .Rows(R).EntireRow.Copy
                .Range(.Rows(R + 1), .Rows(R + 2)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Excel worksheet GUI menu, this is called Insert Copied Cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If Right(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, 7) = "-edubnd" Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 4).Copy
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(2, 4).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next i

    End With '

End Sub
```